# Python MySQL Number Matching

Tags: python, mysql

I am looking for a method of checking all the fields in a MySQL table. Let's say I have a MySQL table with the fields `One` `Two` `Three` `Four` `Five` and `Big One`. These are fields that contains numbers that people enter in, sort of like the Mega Millions. Users enter numbers and it inserts the numbers they picked from least to greatest.

Numbers would be drawn and I need a way of checking if any of the numbers that each user picked matched the winning numbers drawn, same for the `Big One`. If any matched, I would have it do something specific, like if one number or all numbers matched.

I hope you understand what I am saying. Thank you.

Comment: What is your problem? [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: @Kos I have attempted many if statements. The problem is going through the database of all the entries and comparing each one to the winning numbers. I think I might have just have though of something right now. Sorry, for not saying what I tried.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine MySQL has some sort of 'set' logic in it, but if it's lacking, I know Python has sets, so I'll use an example of those in my solution:

1. Create a set with the numbers of the winning ticket:

   `winners = set({11, 22, 33, 44, 55})`
2. For each query, jam all it's numbers into a set too:

   `current_user = set({$query[0], $query[1], $query[2]...$query[4]})`
3. Print out how many overlapping numbers there are:

   `print winners.intersection(current_user)`

And finally, for the 'big one', use an if statement.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: I'll definitely check it out when I get to the computer my code is on. Thanks!